# Weird behaviour with input:checked+i

Tags: html, css

I use a star-rating system on my website. I've got multiple products listed and have 5-stars for each product which are actually radioboxes so users can rate. These stars are just outlines by default, and become filled in to show the current- or user's rating. I overlay an i in order to get them filled.

This all works great, but there's a single item on my list that simply doesn't work, while all the others do. It seems that the `<i>` of the checked input isn't targeted by the css.

Full code, the error is on 'Gorilla Glue' with the empty stars - all the others work: https://jsfiddle.net/ha04cmdf/1/ (sorry, lots of unnessecary CSS, important part at the bottom).

```
<span class="star-rating-user strainrater green" data-strainid="5a037b83f5092735b2239467">
<input class="first" type="radio" name="rating_gorilla-glue" value="1"><i></i>
<input class="second" type="radio" name="rating_gorilla-glue" value="2"><i></i>
<input class="third" type="radio" name="rating_gorilla-glue" checked="true" value="3"><i></i>
<input class="fourth" type="radio" name="rating_gorilla-glue" value="4"><i></i>
<input class="fifth" type="radio" name="rating_gorilla-glue" value="5"><i></i>
</span>


.star-rating-user input:checked+i, .star-rating-shop input:checked+i {
    opacity: 1;
}
.star-rating-user.green i, .star-rating-shop.green i {
    background: green;
    background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating-user i ~ i ~ i, .star-rating-shop i ~ i ~ i {
    width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: I do not figure out that whis one is not working? Can you provide more detail?

Comment: you shared only an irrelevant part of your code that doesn't demonstrate the issue

Comment: Missing ` around the `<i>`

Comment: Maybe I and I am stoned? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmaqdSu5Svo

Comment: there's a ton of code, check the jsfiddle link. The `<i>` after the checked radiobox doesn't seem to get targetted by the css, but only on 1 instance, while all others around it do just fine...

Comment: you said *important part at the bottom* and it's not the case, you should then be more precise because we can close the question as "cannot reproduce" since the *important* code show nothing.

Comment: You have two groups of inputs with the same name `name="rating_gorilla-glue"`. This seems to be the problem.

Comment: What is the actual symptom we need to look at?

Comment: Sorry, I meant at the bottom part of the CSS in the jsfiddle. I cannot reproduce it in a single instance, this issue only shows up if all other code is present.

Answer (score 0):

2 instances of the same name on an input.. Thanks Turnip

Answer (score 0):

changed `rating_gorilla-glue` to `rating_gorilla-glue1` now its working.

`<span class="star-rating-user strainrater green" data-strainid="5a037b83f5092735b2239467">
<input class="first" type="radio" name="rating_gorilla-glue1" value="1"><i></i>
<input class="second" type="radio" name="rating_gorilla-glue1" value="2"><i></i>
<input class="third" type="radio" name="rating_gorilla-glue1" checked="true" value="3"><i></i>
<input class="fourth" type="radio" name="rating_gorilla-glue1" value="4"><i></i>
<input class="fifth" type="radio" name="rating_gorilla-glue1" value="5"><i></i>
</span>`